# How to fiter <src tag and <href tag from blogger json responce

Tags: html, json, jsoup, blogger

```
 "content": "\u003cvideo controls width=800 autoplay\u003e\n    \u003csource src=\"https://srv-file8.gofile.io/download/AEiT5Y/www.4MovieRulz.ch - Sunny Winter (2020) 720p Hindi Part-2 HDRip x264 AAC 500MB.mkv\"\u003e\n\u003c/video\u003e\n\n\u003cdiv class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"\u003e\u003ca href=\"https://extraimage.com/images/2020/07/23/Copy-of-Sunny-Winter-Part2-2020-S01-Hindi-Ullu-Originals-Complete-Web-Series-720p-HDRip-400MB-Download.jpg\" imageanchor=\"1\" style=\"margin-left: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\"\u003e\u003cimg border=\"0\" data-original-height=\"450\" data-original-width=\"800\" /\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cvideo autoplay=\"\" controls=\"\" width=\"800\"\u003e\n\n\n\n"
```

I want to get src url and href url  by using jsoup. I don't know how to do that help me.... Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Element image = document.select("source").first();
String url = image.absUrl("src");